# How do I remove this bar from my NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, android-layout

There is this bar at the bottom of my navigation drawer whenever I open it. [Here is the image of what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3lVF.png)

At first my whole layout was like that but then I removed **android:fitsSystemWindows="true"** which fixed the layout. However, that bar still remained at the bottom of my navigation drawer. How do I remove it?

I will also be leaving me code here:

Here is the activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Location.Location"
    tools:openDrawer="right"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

     <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/drawerNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_menu"
         android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
         android:background="#FFFFFF"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:layout_width="10.08dp"
            android:layout_height="17.63dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="334.9dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="763.6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30.8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/back_arrow"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hamburgerMenuIcon"
            android:layout_width="27.01dp"
            android:layout_height="23.53dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="309.3dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="38.7dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="760.6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="27.8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_hamburger_menu"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="112dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="716dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/century_gothic_bold"
            android:text="SELECT LOCATION"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/locationRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="95dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="173dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="353dp"
            android:scrollbarSize="5dp"
            android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/greyScrollBar"
            android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_track"
            android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="754.86dp"
            android:layout_height="399.99dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="310dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="530dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="84dp"
            android:src="@drawable/city_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my menu.xml for my NavigationDrawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/homeNavigationDrawer"
            android:title="Home"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_home"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/profileNavigationDrawer"
            android:title="Profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_profile"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/changeCityNavigationDrawer"
            android:title="Change City"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_change_city"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/emergencyCallNavigationDrawer"
            android:title="Emergency Call"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_emergency_call_red"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/loginAsGuestNavigationDrawer"
            android:title="Log in as guest"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_login"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/logoutNavigationDrawer"
            android:title="Log out"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_logout"
            />
    </group>
</menu>
```

To add here is the themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Flash" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="navigationViewStyle">@style/Widget.App.NavigationView</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Flash.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.NavigationView" parent="">
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/navigationViewBackground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.App.NavigationView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationView">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.NavigationView</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Flash.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.Flash.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

Here is my manifest.xml content

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Flash" >

        <activity android:name=".MakatiCity.EmergencyCall" />
        <activity android:name=".MakatiCity.Help" />
        <activity android:name=".MakatiCity.Contact" />
        <activity android:name=".MakatiCity.Profile" />
        <activity android:name=".MakatiCity.OtherActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MakatiCity.ReportActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MakatiCity.TrackActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Landing.LandingPage" />
        <activity android:name=".Home.SplashScreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Location.Location" />
        <activity android:name=".Register.Register" />
        <activity android:name=".Login.Login" />
        <activity android:name=".NCR.NCR" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I just can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the code and why does it have that there. I already removed the **strong text *android:fitsSystemWindows="true"* but the NavigationDrawer didn't change at all. What can I do to resolve this?

Here is the [Updated Version of it with implemented Themes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkkYn.png)

Comment: There are 2 `DrawerLayout` in your code

Comment: Do I remove the second one?

Comment: Yes trying removing it , and then check , if still not working , update the code

Comment: It is still not working :(

Comment: Please edit the question with updated code

Comment: Done, I already edited it

Comment: Does the updated code has same issue as shown in images , your code seems to work fine at my end , Also what's the theme added to your activity

Comment: yes it still has the same issue. I don't think that I have set the theme for this activity.

Comment: Then it must be taking application theme , What's the application theme

Comment: Wait I will edit the Question above and add it

Comment: What's the value of  `colorPrimaryVariant` in your theme status bar color. Try once with removing this value `android:statusBarColor`

Comment: I removed it but nothing happend :(

Comment: Try to reduce the elements of your code and try to find out what's causing the issue,  move `ConstraintLayout` at top  and `NavigationView` to the  bottom , Empty the `ConstraintLayout` for testing to if that's the issue,  also if possible test on 2 devices to identify if it's a OS specific or device specific issue

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationView` inherits its background color from `colorSurface` attribute of your app's theme. So, you can either update `colorSurface` attribute of your theme in `styles.xml` or you can change `colorSurface` for your `NavigationView` only.

For changing `colorSurface` for only Navigation view.

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.NavigationView" parent="">
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/navigationViewBackground</item>
</style>
```

Create another theme style to override `materialThemeOverlay` using above `colorSurface` attribute.

```
<style name="Widget.App.NavigationView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationView">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.NavigationView</item>
</style>
```

Set this style to `navigationViewStyle` attribute of your app theme

```
<style name="Theme.Flash" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
     <item name="navigationViewStyle">@style/Widget.App.NavigationView</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I will try this now.

Comment: Do remember to add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your `navigationView`

Comment: To clarifiy, I just have to add those three styles in my themes.xml right? Then, I have to to do this in the colors right? <color name="navigationViewBackground">#FFFFFF</color>.

Comment: Do I test it now or do I need to do something else? Sorry I am new to android studio

Comment: Yeah, you need to add the first two styles to your `themes.xml` and the last one `<item name="navigationViewStyle">@style/Widget.App.NavigationView</item>` in your current theme.

Comment: It's enough, you can test it.

Comment: I will update the question and see if it is correct :)

Comment: It is still the same :(

Comment: Have you added `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your navigation view?

Comment: Yes I did add it

Comment: Check what theme is set in you `manifest` application tag

Comment: I added the manifest file.

Comment: it is set at @style/Theme.Flash what do I set it as instead?

Comment: Your theme is correct. try removing the background from navigationView

Comment: It is still the same :(

Comment: Are you using that grey color somewhere else? Try tracking it's usage.

Comment: I will check it now, but as far as I am aware I am not :(

Comment: I have found where I am using grey. In my scrollbar android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/greyScrollBar"

Comment: Change it's color see if it's changing that bottom navigation color

Comment: No it still didnot change the color of it :(

Comment: If it is a hobby project, you should upload it on Github, I'll take a look. What is going wrong? If it's not, create a new project and add only elements related to the navigation view and try the above solution and see if it works or not. It'll help you to figure out, what is going wrong. And you can upload that demo one to GitHub too, if it doesn't work.

Comment: Will do Thank you!! If it doesn't work I will be commenting again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- write short code in on create method

  getSupportActionBar().hide();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

```
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```